# bootstrap timepicker issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display only Minutes and Seconds uisng BootStrap TimePicker

I was trying this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#TimeDemo').datetimepicker({
          pickDate: false,
           timeFormat: 'mm:ss',

     })
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4BzK/1177/

Could you please tell me how to display only Minutes and Seconds using bootstrap timepicker

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the method:

```
tplGlobal.getTemplate //(line 965 in your JavaScript in jsfiddle.
```

There are only checks for:

- picker.options.useMinutes
- picker.options.useSeconds

But none for the hour option.

Essentially what this means is you can tweak the visibility of minutes and seconds, but not hours, unless you wish to alter the getTemplate method.

You can add seconds to the hours and minutes using format, rather than timeFormat (as in your question).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#TimeDemo').datetimepicker({
      pickDate: false,
       format: 'HH:mm:ss' 
 })
});
```

Or you can set the options specifically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#TimeDemo').datetimepicker({
      pickDate: false,
      useMinutes: true,
      useSeconds: true
 })
});
```

Both options only supplement the hours. Although note that the format in the textbox can be just mm:ss if you use:

```
format: 'mm:ss'
```

However, the dropdown is still hours and minutes.

Comment: Thank you so you mean to say that we cannot hide Hours  unless we customize the getTemplate  ??

Comment: It appears that way, yes. It doesn't look like it'd be a lot of effort to tweak it.